# how can we define output sys refcursor in snowflake

Tags: javascript, oracle, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can some  help in identifing how to define output sys ref cursor like in oracle procedure.
How can we define and fecth value in snowflake

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SYS_REFCURSOR / REF CURSOR is not supported in Snowflake. Because Snowflake does not support a procedural language like Oracle PL/SQL (for now).

Comment: Thanks Ghokan,i have checked the snowflake doumentation on that . But is tehre an alternative way of describing sys cursor in snowflake

Comment: one more qq , how can we by pass "" in the select statement while using AS in select in snowflake procedure

Comment: select type AS "type"\
             FROM abc;"\

Comment: There is no alternative way of describing sys cursor, but if you can explain what you are trying to achieve maybe we can provide an alternative way.

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand the second question about bypassing double-quotes.

Comment: how can we pass the above select statemnt while converting an oracle query to snowflake .

Comment: Nikhil please mark your old questions as resolved when you get the answers, and post new questions for the new topics :)

Comment: sure will do that  thanks Ghokan Atil for the inputs and solution , Much appreciated